# How to move files into a folder and then zip the folder in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a powershell script that lists the files inside a folder based on a specific condition. I need to move all those files into a folder and then zip it. Can someone help me on how to do this please? I am a beginner in powershell :(

This is what I have done till now:

```
   #List all the folders in G:\logfiles
   $folders = (Get-ChildItem -Path "G:\logfiles" | Where-Object {$_.Attributes -eq "Directory"} | Select Fullname)

   #looping all folders
   Foreach ($folder in $folders)
   {
          $files = Get-ChildItem -Path G:\logfiles\$folder | Where{$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
   }
```

Comment: Are you restricted to powershell 2.0? If you have v5.0 you can use the built in cmdlet to zip files. Otherwise you will need to use an external tool, or you could use the [Powershell Community Extensions](https://pscx.codeplex.com/) which should allow you to zip files.

Comment: hey, i can change the version, can you tell me what should be the code in that case?

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to use Powershell 5.0 then you can simply pipe the files to the Compress-Archive cmdlet (e.g. `Compress-Archive -DestinationPath 'Archive.zip'`).

You can also simplify your script by specifying the `-recurse` parameter to `Get-ChildItem` so you don't need to loop over each folder separately (assuming this is what you want)

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -Path "G:\logfiles" | Where{$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath 'Archive.zip'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have been using for a while, as long as you have 7zip installed. I agree with the above statements about PS 5 though.

```
#  setting variable for 7zip
if (-not (test-path "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe")) {throw "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe needed"}
set-alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"


# adding files to zip archive, then removing all the working folders
sz a -tzip $destination $folder
```

I got this info from [this link](http://sqlserverpowershell.com/2011/11/01/compress-a-directory-with-7-zip-and-powershell/). Hope you get it all figured out!

Comment: Hey Niemi, I am using 7zip and this is my script, but I am facing an issue here.

Comment: What issue are you having? I know I only commented on the zipping portion, are you having issues moving the files?